# Windows 7 is not detecting new logitech USB mouse

Tags: windows-7, usb, installation, mouse

Yesterday, my old Microsoft IntelliMouse died. I bought a new Logitech USB mouse with a cable (no wireless) and connected it to my PC. Unfortunately, Windows 7 does not detect it.

1. I have tried to connect an external hard drive to the same port and could access it, so I do not believe the usb port is the issue.
2. The laser (i.e. red light) under the mouse is on.
3. The new mouse did not come with drivers to install, manual says to plug it in while the computer is on, it will detect it.
4. I googled this issue and found out I had to remove the IntelliMouse driver, which I did and rebooted my PC.
5. More Googling suggested to launch the 'add a device' feature, which I did, but the screen is stalling:

[image]

How can I solve this issue? What can I try?

Comment: Have you tried installing drivers from Logitech website?

Comment: +1 for a good question. Install the drivers *first* and with mouse unplugged, and if safe to do so, pause your Anti Virus \ Firewall as well during so. Then plug it in

Comment: @JVerstry - What did you buy exactly?  I also advise you to suspend the real-time capabilities of your security software.

Comment: @Ramhound It is a Logitech M90 mouse, I am searching for drivers...

Comment: Drivers are here (click on downloads tab) http://www.logitech.com/en-gb/support/6562?crid=398&osid=14&bit=64

Comment: I found a solution. Before that, I managed install a Logitech program which indicated that I had the proper drivers installed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Googled deeper and found [this](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itprohardware/thread/4d110faf-ab60-4ba2-aeac-02a283e6fd01). Someone recommended to switch off the PC, remove the battery, wait five minutes, and restart. It works! (I have a - now old - Sony Vaio).

And, unbelievably, my IntelliMouse works again too!